# Как удалить setTimeout, если его надо удалить через некоторое время или может ли данная функция удалить саму себя?

Tags: javascript

Коллеги, есть пример

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
let timer;

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector('span').remove();
    console.log(timer);
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }, 1111);

  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(timer);
  }, 2222);
})
```

```html
<button>Button</button>

<span>Span</span>
```

`setTimeout-ОВ` - будет много, чтобы не загрязнять память, удаляю `setTimeout`,
потом перепроверяя через другой `setTimeout` получаю в ответ, что он еще жив.

> Второй ***setTimeout*** только для проверки

Где я не  прав?

Если прав, то почему в ответ я получаю ***1*** во-втором `setTimeout`?

Comment: получаете true? где?

Comment: @ThisMan, в консоли выдает число один, я грешным делом подумал что это true

Comment: делать cleartimeout внутри обработчика settimeout нет смысла, таймер и так уже отработал и убрался.

Comment: @Grundy, а в чем тогда смысл `cleartimeout `?

Comment: @Air В том, чтобы отменить вызов таймера *до* того, как он произошел.

Comment: @Igor, УУУУУппссссссссс...  Ты щас для меня Америку открыл...  Я то думал грешным делом, что даже после выполнения `setTimeoute` весит в памяти и занимает место

Comment: @Air Я это упомянул в ответе, сразу после примера кода.

Comment: @Igor, все понял..  я это видел, но не о том подумал...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Везде правы.

Он не "жив", а просто значение переменной `timer` не изменилось после присвоения в `timer = setTimeout(...`.

К сожалению, функция `clearTimeout` (и `clearInterval`) не меняет значение переменной, которая подается туда в качестве параметра. Я использую следующий шаблон, позволяющий одним действием останавливать таймер и очищать значение переменной:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
let timer;

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector('span').remove();
    console.log(timer);
    timer = clearTimeout(timer); // !!!
  }, 1111);

  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(timer);
  }, 2222);
})
```

```html
<button>Button</button>

<span>Span</span>
```

Конечно, в данном конкретном случае вызов `clearTimeout` вообще не нужен, так как внутри обработчика таймер уже выстрелил и больше вызван не будет, так что здесь достаточно `timer = null;`.

---

Сначала про `setTimeout.length`.

Свойство `length` объекта-функции - это число ожидаемых аргументов -

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length.

В случае `setTimeout`, обязательный параметр один -

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

функция или код, это и есть значение `setTimeout.length` = `1`.

---

Теперь про то, что `timer = 1`.

Тем, кто имел дело с Windows API, хорошо знакомо понятие "HANDLE". Это некое указание на внутренний объект Windows, который возращается многими API функциями, чтобы в дальнейшем передаваться в другие функции. Для этих "рукояток" объявлены специальные типы, которые часто сводятся к целому числу. Но это вполне может быть преобразованное к целому значение указателя или что-то другое. Главное, чтобы код Windows нашел этот внутренний объект, когда мы сошлемся на него с помощью этого значения.

Что-то очень похожее происходит и с таймерами в Javascipt-е. `setTimeout` нам что-то возвращает. Что это на самом деле - нас волновать не должно. Этого чего-то достаточно, чтобы мы могли остановить таймер, передав это в `clearTimeout`. Судя по тому, что выводится в консоль, `setTimeout` возвращает целое число, похожее на счетчик таймеров, созданных за время жизни страницы. Но это, опять же, никакого значения не имеет и может измениться.

Comment: Igor,  благодарю...  Добротный ответ))))

Comment: Igor, еще вопрос. А что за цифру выдает в консоли? `1`, я грешным делом подумал, что это `true`. После  коммента ***ThisMan*** заглянул в глобальные свойства `window`, там обнаружил `length : 1` у `setTimeout`

Comment: @Air Сейчас допишу в ответ.

Comment: ok.............

Comment: @Air Фу, один из моих самых длинных ответов.

Comment: Igor, еще раз благодарю... Прости больше одного плюса не смогу поставить))))